# How to open an excel file loaded to Listview (WPF) and C#

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview(lstViewOwner) which should display the folder and its files.
I select the path by browsing.. once I give the path to a textbox, based on the path, it should open the folders and its files in a hierarchial way.. I mean

- Folder1
    Excel1.xls
    Excel2.xls
    Excel3.xls
- Folder2
    Excel1.xls
    Excel2.xls

Actually my question is 2 fold.
1. How to create a hierarchial way of displaying in the ListView(If i select the folder up one level.. it should disply the children)
2. How to open the files by clicking on it in the ListView.

This is the WPF Application and using C#.

Please help me
Thanks 
Ramm

Comment: You may find that asking two clear and distinct questions gives you more chance of success...  That's the preferred StackOverflow method as it increases the usefulness to others too!

Answer (score 1):

ListView doesn't lend itself to representing hierarchical data.

You need to either:

1. process you hierarchy first, presenting it to ListView as a flattened collection (perhaps with the name or the tag holding its place in the hierarchy).
2. use a hierarchy aware control, such as TreeView.  You could make the TreeView look like a list-view if you wanted.

For launching, assuming you want to run the associated application, you need to put a clicked/double-clicked handler for the control, this in turn should call ShellExecute with the filename selected.